# How to update game score on facebook ?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have done lot of Google but not found some code snippets or way to do. I have a Facebook integrated game and I want to save the users score, time and rating for each level and other information as "Candy Crush Saga". I've been reading about saving high scores on Facebook, but couldn't find a good beginners tutorial about this.

Does anyone know some good tutorials ?

Basically I want to save Level Name, Level Score, Level Rating, Level Time. User can also see the friend highest score of each level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find everything you need in the Facebook docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/opengraph/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/achievements/

Please make sure to read these first to be able to ask more specific questions.

Comment: Ok my specific question is about how to manager level's score. I can get score of each friend. But I want to get/set each friend score in each level.

Comment: You need to define achievements for this I guess: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/achievements#define_achievements Then you can set the points using the game:points field

Comment: ya currently i am reading this try to understand how it works, thanks for this help.

Comment: i done lot of work but not able to manager level score. Have you any code snippets or link.